# Javascript function doesnt give class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small thing I have to make. I need to give a CSS class to a `div` and this has to change the insides of the `div`. But my button doesn't execute the `onclick` or something. I don't get errors in the console.

```js
function Naampie(){
    document.getElementById("ja").className += " pasta-di-mama";
}
    
Naampie();
```

```css
.pasta-di-mama{
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ja">
        <p>Spaghetti</p>
        <p>Macaroni</p>
        <p>MI</p>
        <p>Pasta Kip</p>
        <p>Pasta Salade</p>
  </div>

  <button onclick="Naampie()">Functie</button>

  <!--<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working?

Comment: You are calling the function ´Naampie()´ when your js loads. Could it be that the class is there from the beginning and you think its not being added because its already there?

Comment: `Naampie();` is already called, so the div should have the class `pasta-di-mama` on-load...

Comment: Maybe it's just a copy-paste mistake, but you're missing a "." before the class name in your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `.` in your CSS declaration to target the class. I'd also recommend using `classList.add` instead of appending to the `className`.

```js
function Naampie() {
  document.getElementById("ja").classList.add("pasta-di-mama");
}

Naampie();
```

```css
.pasta-di-mama {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="ja">
  <p>Spaghetti</p>
  <p>Macaroni</p>
  <p>MI</p>
  <p>Pasta Kip</p>
  <p>Pasta Salade</p>
</div>

<button onclick="Naampie()">Functie</button>
```

Comment: also add the script tag BEFORE the closing body tag i.e INSIDE the body

Answer (score 1):

Try  [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods). You also forgot to precede the class with dot (`.`) in CSS. I will also recommend not use inline event handler:

```js
function Naampie(){
  document.getElementById("ja").classList.add("pasta-di-mama");
}
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', Naampie);
```

```css
.pasta-di-mama{
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="ja">
  <p>Spaghetti</p>
  <p>Macaroni</p>
  <p>MI</p>
  <p>Pasta Kip</p>
  <p>Pasta Salade</p>
</div>

<button id="myBtn">Functie</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classList.add("className")`

```js
function Naampie(){
document.getElementById("ja").classList.add("pasta-di-mama");
}

Naampie();
```

```css
.pasta-di-mama{
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Shit</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="ja">
            <p>Spaghetti</p>
            <p>Macaroni</p>
            <p>MI</p>
            <p>Pasta Kip</p>
            <p>Pasta Salade</p>
        </div>

    <button onclick="Naampie()">Functie</button>

</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution looks good, but i will suggest not to execute Naampie immediately after declaration as it seems to me you are trying to add class after the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try add Class

```
function Naampie(){
document.getElementById("ja").classList.add("pasta-di-mama");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it...add an event listener to the btn.

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("ja").classList.add("pasta-di-mama");
});
```

```css
.pasta-di-mama {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="ja">
  <p>Spaghetti</p>
  <p>Macaroni</p>
  <p>MI</p>
  <p>Pasta Kip</p>
  <p>Pasta Salade</p>
</div>

<button id="myBtn">Functie</button>
```